# How to modify XML Soap response with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

I have a relatively simple Soap response message XML which I'd like to modify with XSLT.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:z="http://some.url/WS/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name="Method" select="name(//soap:Body/*)" />

    <xsl:template match="//soap:Body/*" >
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$Method='Method1Response'">
          <xsl:call-template name="Method1" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>

        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>      
    </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template name="Method1" match="//soap:Body/z:Method1Response/z:Method1Result/z:Errors" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">
<env:Header xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <wsa:Action></wsa:Action>
  <wsa:MessageID></wsa:MessageID>
  <wsa:RelatesTo></wsa:RelatesTo>
  <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
</env:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <Method1Response xmlns="http://some.url/WS/">
      <Method1Result>
        <Msg>blah blah</Msg>
        <Errors>
          <ErrorItem>error 1</ErrorItem>
          <ErrorItem>error 2</ErrorItem>
        </Errors>
        <Data />
      </Method1Result>
    </Method1Response>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The idea is to delete the Errors from under Method1Result, if Method1 = specific value. If not, leave it as is. What I currently have, itsn't doing it. Thanks.

Another edit to further clarify:
I want to have a single XSLT file for multiple XML files which belong to different web service calls. Thise means that Method1 can have a number of different values for example: GetMeal, GetWindow, GetHandle, GetWeatherReport,... I'm hoping to create a "case" for each value within the same XSLT in order to intentionally 'break' the expected XML for testing purposes. Each time I will delete a different element.

Comment: Please, edit the question and specify the exact wanted result from the transformation.

Comment: You leave us guessing which are the "few elements from under Method1Result" that should be deleted and what is "specific value" in "if Method1 = specific value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the template that matches **`//soap:Body/*`** calls a named template which itself does not output anything. This results in all elemenets under **soap:Body** being ignored.

As you already have a template to match the elements you want to remove, you can remove the template that matches **soap:Body** and you should find it will work as expected.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" 
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
    xmlns:z="http://some.url/WS/"> 
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/> 

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()"> 
      <xsl:copy> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/> 
      </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="//soap:Body/z:Method1Response/z:Method1Result/z:Errors" /> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when this applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">
   <env:Header xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
      <wsa:Action/>
      <wsa:MessageID/>
      <wsa:RelatesTo/>
      <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
   </env:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <Method1Response xmlns="http://some.url/WS/">
         <Method1Result>
            <Msg>blah blah</Msg>
            <Data/>
         </Method1Result>
      </Method1Response>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

EDIT: There is no reason why you can't have further matching templates to handle other method responses you might get back. For example....

```
<xsl:template match="//soap:Body/z:GetMealResponse/z:GetMealResult/z:Leftovers" />
<xsl:template match="//soap:Body/z:Method1Response/z:Method1Result/z:Errors" />
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I had in mind as it only solves half of my problem. I already had the solution you describe and I wanted to expand it to involve the $Method variable. I want to be able to show/hide the errors based on that variable's value. Hence the xsl:choose tag etc. I obviously don't really understand how this works :)

Comment: There is no reason why you can't have multiple templates in the XSLT, one for each of your expected cases. Perhaps adding a second sample XML with a different case would help explain things better? Thanks!

Comment: This last example actually solves it, thanks :) I can't believe it's so simple!

Answer (score 0):

From your stylesheet sample:

```
<xsl:variable name="Method" select="name(//soap:Body/*)" />

<xsl:template match="//soap:Body/*" >
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$Method='Method1Response'">
      <xsl:call-template name="Method1" />
```

Get rid of the variable `$Method`, you don't need it.

Note *match patterns* (as in `match="//soap:Body/*"`, which is awkward), in contrast to *search expressions (as in `select="name(//soap:Body/*)"`) can usually be fairly simple and don't need the search-the-whole-doc operator (so you'd simplify to `match="soap:Body/*"`).

Instead of using explicit conditional logic, just supply a template that will match your special case and make sure it has a higher priority than other candidate templates so it will match:

```
<xsl:template match="z:Method1Response"/><!-- suppressed -->
```

Or with explicit raised priority:

```
<xsl:template match="z:Method1Response" priority="2"/>
```

Or more specifically for contained errors:

```
<xsl:template match="z:Method1Response[z:Method1Result/z:Errors]"/>
```